# Cloud Run Run/Debug has stopped working - Exited with code 127

Tags: google-cloud-shell, skaffold, google-cloud-code

The cloudrun debug in cloud shell was working. It is no longer working for me with the following output.

I have 1) rebooted the VM and 2) I have tried another project that was also working previously.

I suspect something has changed in my environment

> Starting to debug the app using configuration 'Cloud Run: Run/Debug
> Locally' from .vscode/launch.json... To view more detailed logs, go to
> Output channel : "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally - Detailed" Dependency
> check started Dependency check succeeded Unpausing minikube flag needs
> an argument: --status-check See 'skaffold debug --help' for usage.
> Exited with code 127. Cleaning up... Finished clean up.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was introduced in the v1.17.1 release of Cloud Code for VS Code, due to a change in [v1.37.0](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/releases/tag/v1.37.0) of Skaffold related to the `--status-check` parameter. This bug was addressed in [v1.17.2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes) of Cloud Code for VS Code, and upgrading to this version (or later) should fix this issue.

Comment: Thank You David, this is very helpful. I am using google cloud shell as the IDE. Any ideas on how to update that? Perhaps a question I need to ask google?

Comment: Ah, apologies for the misunderstanding! Unfortunately the answer I've provided won't unblock you in this case. I've reached out to the Cloud Shell team to see what can be done, I or they will update as soon as possible!

Comment: Hi @StewartBell Did you figure out a way to fix this issue in google cloud shell?  I am also using google cloud shell and experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @david-ponder, I'm curious whether you heard back from the Cloud Shell team.  I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Apologies for the delay! The Cloud Shell team is aware of the issue and is working to roll out a fix; I'll update here once there's a timeframe you can expect to see the change on your ends.

Comment: Hey all, thank you once again for the patience! The Cloud Shell team has rolled out a fix that should start appearing this week. Thanks again!